Column list validation
I created additional columns in a list using Yes/No type for the first one. It gave me option to use yes as default value for that check box. However, the user needs to see both yes/No as boxes as options to select and if 'yes' is selected, then the second column will be visible for input of additional information but if 'No' is selected, then the second column shouldn't be visible.
How can I achieve this pls?

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2020/12/sharepoint-online-show-hide-form-field-based-on-another-fields-value-using-conditional-formula.html
